# Questions on the Trumpet and Vial Judgments of the book of Revelation

Tags: revelation

I have three questions:

1) What is the scriptural basis for the assertion that the 7th Trumpet of the book of Revelation contains the 7 Vial judgments? I am unable to find a satisfactory scriptural support for this assertion. I can understand it when we say the 7th Seal comprises the 7 Trumpets, but I don't see any scriptures that support the view that the Seventh Trumpet contains the 7 Vials. If you have any scripture that supports this view, could you share it with me?

2) If the 7th Trumpet sounds at the end of the Tribulation (i.e. on the final day of the great Tribulation) as Revelation 11:15-19 appears to indicate, it cannot contain the 7 Vials because all 7 Vials are not poured out on the final day of the Tribulation. My understanding is that only the 7th Vial is poured out on the final day of the Tribulation, which means Vials #1-6 have to be poured out before the final day of the great Tribulation. If this is correct, it means the outpouring of Vials 1-6 occurs BEFORE the sounding of the 7th Trumpet on the last day of the Tribulation. Thus, on the final day of the Tribulation just before Jesus Christ returns to earth, the 7th Trumpet sounds and the 7th Vial is poured out. Following the sounding of the 7th Trumpet on the final day of the Tribulation, rejoicing breaks out in heaven with voices saying "The kingdoms of this world have become the kingdoms of our Lord and His Christ......"

If my understanding is correct, it means the Trumpets and Vials are not sequential since the pouring out of Vials #1-6 will be occurring before the sounding of the 7th Trumpet. What do you think? Do let me know if I am missing anything here.

3) What is the correct interpretation of Revelation 10:7: " But in the days of the voice of the seventh angel, when he shall begin to sound, the mystery of God should be finished, as he hath declared to his servants the prophets."

First, what exactly is meant by "the mystery of God" in this context? Secondly, does this verse mean that the mystery of God will be finished at the very moment the 7th Trumpet BEGINS to sound or during the sounding?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to BHSE! We're a little different here, if you please read our [Site Directives](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/asking), it will help you in asking and answering questions. Thank you!

Comment: I would break these questions up into 3 separate questions, as an answer could be more focused. Thank you!

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/11638/is-the-7th-seal-opened-before-the-6th-seal-book-of-revelation?rq=1- Could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I will try and answer your first question:

If you look at Revelation 11:19, when the Seventh Trumpet was sounded, the temple of God was opened in heaven and the ARK OF HIS COVENANT was seen; This shows that the second Vail was opened into the Most Holy Place;

Comparing that with Revelation 15:5, the same temple was opened into the Most Holy Place;
This opening is the same one described in Revelation 11:19 at the sounding of the Seventh Trumpet;

And in Revelation 15, as soon as the Temple is opened into the Holiest Place, Seven Angels come out of the Temple to pour out their Vials:

THEREFORE, THE SEVEN VIALS COME OUT OF THE SEVENTH TRUMPET;

You can correspond with me on this address:
ebsondekete@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I agree that the vials come after the seven Trumpets. I'm studying now and as far as I can see, each of the Trumpets directly corresponds to the same number vial. I think this is two ways of interpreting the same events. Go look and compare. It's uncanny how they are the same. Revelation is highly symbolic and it's basically like a dream. Dreams don't often happen in sequential or chronological order. It jumps around a bit here and there. Continue to ask God for wisdom and discernment. Read and re-read Revelation and the whole Bible. Especially the prophets. It will paint a clearer picture.

Comment: Welcome to BH. May I suggest that you do not presume to tell other users what to do : 'Go look and compare' 'Read and re-read ...' We are all here to learn and none of us has the right to tell another what to do in their spare time. Please have a look at the Tour and the Help (below). I agree with what you say about symbolism and about dreams. Good points.

Answer (score 0):

This is in regard to Revelation 10:7, in the days of the voice of the 7th angel when he shall sound the trumpet the mystery of God should be finished as He has declared to his servant the prophets.
The 7th angel is here is not a heavenly angel but the angel of the 7th church age which the angel messenger to the Laodicean church age and the the angel fulfills Malachi 4:5-6 and Luke 17:30 and who of course must be a prophet like John the Baptist who introduced the first coming of the Lord Jesus for the Lord God does nothing without first revealing it to His servants the prophets. Amos (3:7) Remember how the Son of Man was revealed to Abraham in Genesis 18 and how He was revealed in the time of Jesus and He promised the same thing will be done before the rapture take place.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics.  Please take our Tour to understand what we look for in a well-researched answer: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Welcome, Paul. There are 3 questions to be answered, so if you could delineate them sequentially and make a progressive answer, that might be helpful. It also helps if you can quote authorities on the subject instead of giving what appears to just be your opinion or personal interpretation. If you could add more to your answer that would be good.